# How much RAM memory should I allocate for Ubuntu when running a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation

How much memory should I allocate to the host OS (in my case, Ubuntu 12.04) if I run Windows 7 Ultimate on a virtual machine (I want it for some gaming)?

I have 4 GB of RAM. If I allocate 3512 MB RAM for Windows 7, or if I allocate even more for it, will everything still be ok?

Comment: Well that depends on like a million things, what will you be using Ubuntu for? Video editing? Gaming? coding? just testing desktop environments?

Comment: @olli do not edit questions in the close queue!

Comment: @Braiam okay, if I understand correctly, editing questions in the close queue (even if I think it shouldn't be closed) is not ok, but editing closed questions for sake of making those better (and not because after editing it should be opened) is ok?

Comment: @Olli http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8119/169736

Comment: @Braiam did you actually read my reply? I edited it because I think it shouldn't be closed. If I didn't edit it, I would have clicked "Keep Open". As far as I know, editing is same as clicking "Keep Open" & opening question in new tab and editing it there.

Comment: @Olli no, you pushed the Q outside the review queue and didn't changed anything that could make reviewers change of opinion. The correct step here is Leave Open and do "formatting, spelling" edit outside the queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 minimum memory [requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/minimum-hardware-reqts.html) suggest at least 512 megabytes for a desktop install.

Visit https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm, they give similar recommendations.

So I would not go below 512MB for sure. But prefer keeping 1024MB if you see your host swap being actively used though.